# Making A Control Visible Through Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, onclick, label

I have a label and a div called "menu" that  is currently invisible. I want that when the user clicks the label. It will make the div visible. I thought of doing it through javascript, how do I make a control visible through javascript?

Comment: If the control has a Visible="false" on the server side, the control is not rendered, thus not accessible by JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you want to access controls on the client-side, they must be rendered as html. When you use [Control.Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible%28VS.90%29.aspx) it won't be rendered on the client and is only accessible on the serverside. Therefore you have to use CSS to toggle it's visibility on the clientside.

show the div:

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'inherit';
```

You could hide it with:

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
```

You should keep in mind that the id of serverside-controls could change when it's inside of an other [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) than the page(f.e. in a GridView or UserControl). So you should use [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) to get the correct ID that'll be generated from ASP.Net:

So this is better:

```
document.getElementById('<%= menu.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

In ASP.Net 4.0 it's possible to customize the ClientID. For further informations:

- http://www.thereforesystems.com/working-with-client-id-in-asp-net-4/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx